# getline won't let me type,  c++

Tags: c++, getline

I try to get the name of a game the users chooses and store it in a vector.
I use getline so the user can use a space.
When I try to type a new game to add it won't let me.
It automaticly displays me games library.
Please tell me what I do wrong.
Problem is at 
    if(action == "add")

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     vector<string>::const_iterator myIterator;
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;                

vector<string> games;                                
games.push_back("Crysis 2");
games.push_back("GodOfWar 3");
games.push_back("FIFA 12");

cout <<"Welcome to your Games Library.\n";
cout <<"\nThese are your games:\n";
for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout <<*iter <<endl;
}
//the loop!
string action;
string newGame;

cout <<"\n-Type 'exit' if you want to quit.\n-Type 'add' if you want to add a game.\n-Type 'delete' if you want to delete a game.\n-Type 'find' if you want to search a game.\n-Type 'game' if you don't know what game to play.\n-Type 'show' if you want to view your library.";

while (action != "exit")
{


    cout <<"\n\nWhat do you want to do: ";
    cin >> action;

              //problem is here
    if (action == "add")
    {
        cout <<"\nType the name of the game you want to add: ";
        getline (cin, newGame);

        games.push_back(newGame);

        for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
        {
            cout <<*iter <<endl;
        }

        continue;
    }
    else if (action == "show")
    {
        cout <<"\nThese are your games:\n";
        for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
        {
            cout <<*iter <<endl;
        }
    }
    else if (action == "delete")
    {
        cout <<"Type the name of the game you want to delete: ";
        cin >> newGame;
        getline (cin, newGame);

        iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), newGame);

        if(iter != games.end())
        {
            games.erase(iter);
            cout <<"\nGame deleted!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nGame not found.";
        }

        continue;
    }
    else if (action == "find")
    {
        cout <<"Which game you want to look for in your library: ";
        cin >> newGame;
        getline (cin, newGame);

        iter = find(games.begin(), games.end(), newGame);

        if (iter != games.end())
        {
            cout << "Game found.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Game not found.\n";
        }

        continue;
    }
    else if (action == "game")
    {
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
        random_shuffle(games.begin(), games.end());
        cout << "\nWhy don't you play " << games[0];

        continue;
    }
    else if (action == "quit")
    {
        cout <<"\nRemember to have fun while gaming!!\n";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"\nCommand not found";
    }
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You don't need cin >> newGame, because getline(cin, newGame); does what you need.

Comment: why do you use both **cin** and **getline**?

Comment: @dexametason nope when i use getline it won't let me type a new game to add

Comment: @Stijn: just remove the 3rd line of your code it must work. Maybe you have a new_line from the previous value read...

Comment: What's more you should always create a variable as close as you can where you use (ex.:iter, newGame).

Comment: @Stijn: try not mixing cin and getline in your code. Use getline everywhere, give a try :)

Comment: `getline` and `cin` are conflicting due to the way they internally work. `cin` has been long considered inferior to getline as it doesnt capture `'\n` properly. So `getline(cin, MyString);`is pretty much standard now. (just wrote this to explain further what other people have been writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you exactly wrote, but:

- `getline` will fetch the whole line in its second parameter in your case `newGame`
- when you call `cin >> newGame;` above the getline, you frst use the `istream operator >>` of `string`. It reads until the first separator. This in your case is the space between `Tomb` and `Raider`
- Afterwords you overwrite the value read with `cin >> newGame;` using the `getline`. Until the `getline` the value was `Tomb`, afterwords it becomes `Raider`

Just remove the `cin`:

```
cin >> newGame;
getline (cin, newGame);
```

->

```
getline (cin, newGame);
```

**EDIT** Now as you posted all your code I am sure your case is exactly what I thought of. In the line `cin >> action;` you prompt the user to select an action. He enters it and hits enter so he can make your program active once more. However, the `cin >>` will read the value, but not clear the enter the user pressed. Thus the first `getline` you invoke will just read this enter and nothing else. If you do:

```
cin >> newGame;
getline (cin, newGame);
```

->

```
cin.get();
getline (cin, newGame);
```

This will work. I tried it. Basically the first `cin.get();` clears the enter and the `getline` prompts the user for input.

**EDIT2** Adding one more improvement on the lay the trailing new lines are handled. This is maybe the most correct way to handle them, but I intentionally did not provide this solution trying not to confuse the OP with complex code:

```
   if (cin.peek() == '\n' || cin.peek() == '\r') {
      cin.get();
   }
   getline (cin, newGame);
```

Comment: I did that before but the problem is that the program doesn't let me type something. Whit that I mean that when it says:"Type the name of the game you want to add" it wont let me the chance to type something and it automaticly displays all my games.

Comment: Strange. It should I tested that. The only reason why it will not let you input anything is that you have not cleared the newline from previous value read (say an integer). Duplicate the `getline` and this should be fixed (the first one will clear out the new line symbol).

Comment: I will put on all the code maybe my mistake is somewhere else

Comment: Ok and in the mean time try also duplicating the `getline`: `getline (cin, newGame); getline (cin, newGame);`

Comment: Yess!!! It works, thank you so much, I learned allot man. You just made a 15 year old boy's day :)

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for the accept. I have improved my answer a bit more. Please consider the last edit. This is neater solution.

Comment: How about reading the `action` via `getline` as well -- it will work well, without the need for stary `cin.get()`s.  For that matter, do all input via `getline` (see my answer for details).

Comment: @Attila Basically you are right. In some cases, however, you should agree that is not always possible. E.g if `action` is integer then you can read it in `string` with `getline` and then convert it to integer. However this is with terrible performance and sometimes it is not an option. Basically I restrain from so strong statements as `never mix`. Let him know how to deal with the situation and then he can decide based on the situation using his own brains.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - I agree that it might not be the most efficient, but I find that teaching others ideas that will lead to creating _correct_ programs is better than telling them how to fix the immediate problem they face with a convenient easy fix that will not eliminate the confusion that lead to asking the question in the first place.  Once they can write correct programs and find it too slow, then they can ask questions about how to make it more efficient -- in this particular case the efficiency gain is minimal, the teaching potential is large.

Comment: @Attila Actually I wouldn't say this is not correct program writing. Maybe the most correct way is the one I provide in my second edit. However I intentionally didn't mention it in order not to confuse the OP.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - and now they will litter their code with `cin.peek` guard everywhere they use `getline`, just to make sure it will work correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing

```
cin >> value1;
```

and

```
getline(cin, value2);
```

is inviting trouble.  The problem is that `getline` reads until the next '\n' (and consumes it), while `>>` reads until the next white-space (and does not consume it).

This means that when you read `value1` via `>>`, the new-line character remains in the stream, then you try to read a whole line and read "nothing" (the `getline` will consume the new-line character that is the immediate input from the stream).

Suggestions of doubling the `getline` will work, but only until you read via `getline` in another branch, when it will break, because that `getline` consumes the new-line, contrary to `>>`, which does not.

I suggest you handle all your input via `getline`, then tokenize the read string, if further processing is needed.  This way ou ensure that the new-line handling is consistent and also that spaces are read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
cout <<"Type the name of the game you want to add: ";
```

instead of your this code:

```
cout <<"\nType the name of the game you want to add: ";
```

I am not sure whether it works or not. but please give a try.

Comment: It does not help, because the output (`<<`) has nothing to do with the input (`>>`) from the standpoint of the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe because of a stray '\n'. getline as the name suggests gets the values of the complete line. So how does your compiler know when you have finished. It uses the character `\n`. If it reads a left over `\n` it will assume that the line has ended, so if u remove it i think it should work.So just find out the line before the getline which may have left a stray \n.